# PDEs: Conceptual understanding of "contour lines"

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, homogeneous-equation

I am struggling with a concept introduced in a third year undergraduate course on "Mathematical Methods"; specifically at the very beginning of the chapter on PDEs. Contour Lines are introduced, followed later by Data Curves.

Contour Lines are defined as follows:

Consider a linear, homogeneous PDE

$$a(x,y)u_x+b(x,y)u_y=0$$
with $a^2 + b^2 \neq 0$.

This may be solved by considering the solutions of

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{b}{a}(x,y) \hspace{20mm} (*)$$

for any initial point $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$,

This yields many trajectory lines, each with tangents parallel to

$$\begin{pmatrix}b(x,y)\\a(x,y)\end{pmatrix}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

It is then proven that u is constant along the solutions of the PDE. Then it says

As $u(x(t),y(t))$ is constant along (x(t),y(t)), a solution to the PDE, the curves $(x(t),y(t))$ describe *contour lines* of u. Different values of u are taken, depending on $(x_0,y_0)$.

I have problems with understanding the above. I understand the given PDE, and understand that it can be solved for any initial point $(x_0,y_0)$. I don't understand why considering solutions of $(*)$ solves the given PDE. I don't understand what "This yields many trajectory lines, each with tangents parallel to..." means. I mean to say that I don't really understand what that vector represents, what trajectory lines are, or why the tangents to the trajectory lines should be parallel to it. Perhaps I should emphasize that this is one of the main issues.

The proof is given of u being constant along the solutions to the PDE. I think I understand that, so have not included it.

As far as I understand what comes next, I understand that there is a solution $(x(t),y(t))$ (a parametrized curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$), and I can visualize how, if u is constant along this curve, this somehow looks like a contour line on a map. Things break down now, because I don't really understand why I'm visualizing some sort of "hilly" region in $\mathbb{R}^3$, even though I am doing that and that seems to make sense in the context of the lecture notes. Is that hilly region just what $u(x,y)$ "looks like"?

Any help is appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is described here is the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). Try looking up the geometric interpretation of this method, it makes a lot of sense. Take [this as an example](http://www.ehu.eus/luis.escauriaza/apuntes_problemas_y_examene/method-of-characteristics.pdf)...